# Get data from $.ajax object

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

How can I get data from $.ajax
Example:

```
var ajax = $.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json'
});

ajax.url // undefined
// But I need
ajax.url // http://example.com
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. [`jqXHR` objects](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), such as `ajax`, don't have properties for (much of?) the request options in the [`settings` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) passed to `$.ajax()`.

But, you can keep `settings` separately and retrieve request info from it as needed:

```
var settings = {
  url: 'http://example.com',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json'
};

var ajax = $.ajax(settings);

console.log(settings.url);
```

And, if needed, you can attach `settings` to `ajax` yourself:

```
// ...

var ajax = $.ajax(settings);
ajax.settings = settings;
```

```
console.log(ajax.settings.url);
```

Comment: So in a sentence, the answer is "No, without modifying the code creating the XHR you can't" ? I see you've edited your answer, you can make the top part more decisive. The answer indeed is "no". http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.ajax see the jqXHR bit :) +1 and cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It was needed for test so I did this way

```
  var ajax = $.ajax({
    url: '/signin',
    data: { user: 'ButuzGOL' },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
  });
  ajax.abort();
  ajax.always(function() {
    expect(this.type).to.be('POST');
    expect(this.url).to.be('/signin');
    expect(this.data).to.be({ user: 'ButuzGOL' });

    done();
  });
```